# How to construct and manage this complex C data structure?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I'm quite confusing how to efficiently manage (populating and accessing) the following data structure in C. To describe in brief, I have a struct that contains a member of another struct, and that struct has a member of another different struct and so forth. Something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
} D;

typedef struct
{
    D *boo;
} C;

typedef struct
{
    C *far;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    B *bar;
} A;

A *func() {
    A *var;
    // POPULATE var
}

int main(...) {
    A *a = func();
    // PRINTING
}
```

So, which way is the best way to manage this data structure? I mean how am I going to populate the data for this A-typed pointer?

Imagine that I'm about to print all the data that `a` keeps (at `// PRINTING`), I guess I'm gonna have something like: `a->bar->far->boo->num`. I don't know whether this properly works and thus, is robust.

Comment: The first thing you might want to do is replace each single-member `struct` with a `typedef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't be any easier in e.g. Python, if you're selecting such a scattered design then it's going to be a bit painful to manage, naturally.

The printing would work just as you say, C's `->` operator is typically used just like that. Of course, if there can be NULL pointers where the structure is not "complete" you need to check for that before dereferencing the pointer, or you will have undefined behavior.

Population would probably be best done by writing functions to create an instance at each layer, which can then call each other in a chain to set up the top-most type:

```
D* d_create(int num);
C* c_create(int num);
B* b_create(int num);

A* a_create(int foo, int num)
{
   A* a = malloc(sizeof *a);
   if(a != NULL)
   {
     a->foo = foo;
     a->bar = b_create(num);
     if(a->bar != NULL)
       return a;
     free(a);
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

This is a bit cumbersome since all the actual data (`foo` and `num`) must be passed in to the top-level function that creates an instance of `A`, but it works and is very straight-forward.

Notice how we catch errors from the lower-level memory allocators, by making sure the `B` pointer is non-`NULL`. These kinds of checks would be necessary in the other `create`-functions, too.

Comment: +1 for such a nice answer, I'll think more about this and get back to you soon.

Comment: hey **unwind**, just a quick question: how can you free(a) after returning it? Does the program will still execute the free() function?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to answer "how do I manage this", without knowing why you've chosen to use pointers. If each `A` owns its own `B` and so on, then you need to allocate the `B` when you allocate the `A`, and free it when you free the `A`. But in that case the pointer is useless and creates extra work. You could just have done:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
} D;

typedef struct
{
    D boo;
} C;

typedef struct
{
    C far;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    B bar;
} A;

A func() { // don't necessarily need to return a pointer here either
    A var;
    var.foo = 1;
    var.bar.far.boo.num = 2;
    return var;
}
```

If the reason for the pointer is that you could have several instances of `A` that all point to the same instance of `B`, then you need to decide how you will know when that instance of `B` is no longer in use and can be freed. There are some general-purpose solutions like reference counting, or there might be something specific to your application that makes the answer to the question easy.